# Attempting to ignore spaces when building array of user input in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix, cin, getline

I am attempting to build a 2d matrix that is in a word search program. The sample input I am given has spaces in the string, and I am not sure how to ignore the spaces and just have an array of characters. I will attach my code block that pertains to filling the 2d matrix. I believe I need getline() here, but am rather new and not sure how to implement it. The program runs fine if I do not use spaces.

```
void fill_matrix(int rows, int cols, char **matrix)
{
    string Matrix1 = " ";
    cout << "Enter the array" << endl;
    cin >> Matrix1;         //getline()? 
    cin.ignore();
    cout << endl;
    int x = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
      for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
      {
        matrix[i][j] = Matrix1[x];
        x++;
      }
    }

    return;

}
```

Sample_input:

```
4

7 7
u c d z q c y
k i m i f z e
k r u c s i p
h o a w b y w
n m o b h o y
s q j e r i x
w u n t g a x
bark
```

Comment: Yes, you need `getline`. `std::cin` on its own stops after the first space in input. Use `std::getline(std::cin, Matrix1)`.

Comment: Substituting `cin >> Matrix1` with `std::getline(std::cin, Matrix1)` did not stop it from skipping over spaces

Comment: What is the actual input you need to read? What is the output you need to get? Perhaps you should read multiple times? And you definitely should check for string out of bounds access. Please [edit] your question to improve it, and also please take some time to read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Edited, added sample input. When copying and pasting the array of letters into the program when running it, it includes the spaces. I must ignore those when passing them into my own array. Only the block of spaced out letters is what I am attempting to `std::getline(std::cin, Matrix1)`

Comment: It looks like you could skip the `Matrix1` variable completely, and basically just use `std::cin >> matrix[i][j]` in the loops.